# check if certain char sequences exists in a string builder and remove it

Tags: replace, substring, stringbuilder

in java, I am trying to find if a given string has one of the many sub strings using multiple ORs in a single If condition and if any of the sub string exists, remove it. I am not sure how to do it. Also, this string search needs to be case insensitive.

Here is the sample code

```
if (inputString contains any of the subStrings i.e. "_LOCATION" OR "_MANAGEMENT" Or   "_ZIPCODE")
{
   remove the subString from inPutString
}
```

Ex: Given the string - "STATE_CAPITAL_LOCATION_MANAGEMENT_PHONE_EMAIL_zipcode"

Resulting string should be - "STATE_CAPITAL_PHONE_EMAIL"

What is the best way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using separate `If` statements makes more easier.

Try this code:

```
String a="STATE_CAPITAL_LOCATION_MANAGEMENT_PHONE_EMAIL_zipcode";
    if(a.contains("_LOCATION"))// relace with your string
    {
        a=a.replace("_LOCATION","");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
   if(a.contains("_MANAGEMENT"))// relace with your string
    {
        a=a.replace("_MANAGEMENT","");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    // .....
```

Comment: Thanks @ling.s for the solution. This should obviously work. Since the list of substrings to be removed is long, I was wondering if there is a slick way to do it. Also, this is not case insensitive. I guess, I will have to add another OR withing the if () to check that or use a string.ToUpperCase type of solution. 

Thanks anyway